# using qglcontext from other threads

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

Is there a way to use the qglcontext of the glwidget from other threads. Because I need to do some texture uploading from other threads. However after the texture upload or even during it context must be also in the service of my rendering glwidget. Is there a documentation or a solid (assumption free) answer for this?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Mykola Note that OP might have a strange behaviour on some answers by not providing any feedback at all. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317470/what-can-i-do-if-a-user-removes-a-question-after-ive-written-an-extended-answer) meta for example.

Comment: @eAbi: I have already had bad thing about this.

Comment: @eAbi: Still I hope my answer can help other people, who read this post.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL does not support multithreaded rendering, all OpenGL calls must be performed from the thread where context was created. But if you whant to just load textures, you may load it from other threads, than post the results to that thread from wich OpenGL context was created for example to `glTexImage2D`, as image info. To do so must be add some thread management (signals e.t.c...).

For more information look at [Concurrency and OpenGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html).

also [QGLWidget multithreaded example?](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41095-QGLWidget-multithreaded-example).

To work from other threads you must create separate contexts with them or perform some sharing context management.

---

From official Qt documentation:

As of Qt version 4.8, support for doing threaded GL rendering has been improved. There are three scenarios that we currently support:

1. Buffer swapping in a thread.
   Swapping buffers in a double buffered context may be a synchronous, locking call that may be a costly operation in some GL implementations. Especially so on embedded devices. It's not optimal to have the CPU idling while the GPU is doing a buffer swap. In those cases it is possible to do the rendering in the main thread and do the actual buffer swap in a separate thread. This can be done with the following steps:

   1. Call `doneCurrent()` in the main thread when the rendering is finished.
   2. Call `QGLContext::moveToThread(swapThread)` to transfer ownership of the context to the swapping thread.
   3. Notify the swapping thread that it can grab the context.
   4. Make the rendering context current in the swapping thread with `makeCurrent()` and then call `swapBuffers()`.
   5. Call `doneCurrent()` in the swapping thread.
   6. Call `QGLContext::moveToThread(qApp->thread())` and notify the main thread that swapping is done.

Doing this will free up the main thread so that it can continue with, for example, handling UI events or network requests. Even if there is a context swap involved, it may be preferable compared to having the main thread wait while the GPU finishes the swap operation. Note that this is highly implementation dependent.

2. Texture uploading in a thread.
   Doing texture uploads in a thread may be very useful for applications handling large amounts of images that needs to be displayed, like for instance a photo gallery application. This is supported in Qt through the existing `bindTexture()` API. A simple way of doing this is to create two sharing `QGLWidgets`. One is made current in the main GUI thread, while the other is made current in the texture upload thread. The widget in the uploading thread is never shown, it is only used for sharing textures with the main thread. For each texture that is bound via `bindTexture()`, notify the main thread so that it can start using the texture.
3. Using `QPainte`r to draw into a `QGLWidget` in a thread.
   In Qt 4.8, it is possible to draw into a `QGLWidget` using a `QPainter` in a separate thread. Note that this is also possible for `QGLPixelBuffers` and `QGLFramebufferObjects`. Since this is only supported in the GL 2 paint engine, OpenGL 2.0 or OpenGL ES 2.0 is required.

`QGLWidgets` can only be created in the main GUI thread. This means a call to `doneCurrent()` is necessary to release the GL context from the main thread, before the widget can be drawn into by another thread. You then need to call `QGLContext::moveToThread()` to transfer ownership of the context to the thread in which you want to make it current. Also, the main GUI thread will dispatch resize and paint events to a `QGLWidget` when the widget is resized, or parts of it becomes exposed or needs redrawing. It is therefore necessary to handle those events because the default implementations inside `QGLWidget` will try to make the `QGLWidget`'s context current, which again will interfere with any threads rendering into the widget. Reimplement `QGLWidget::paintEvent()` and `QGLWidget::resizeEvent()` to notify the rendering thread that a resize or update is necessary, and be careful not to call the base class implementation. If you are rendering an animation, it might not be necessary to handle the paint event at all since the rendering thread is doing regular updates. Then it would be enough to reimplement `QGLWidget::paintEvent()` to do nothing.

As a general rule when doing threaded rendering: be aware that binding and releasing contexts in different threads have to be synchronized by the user. A GL rendering context can only be current in one thread at any time. If you try to open a `QPainter` on a `QGLWidget` and the widget's rendering context is current in another thread, it will fail.

In addition to this, rendering using raw GL calls in a separate thread is supported.